# I tried to see the implementation of tether() method of ConnectivityManager class and I came up with this

Tags: android

```
public int tether(String iface) {
   try {
        return mService.tether(iface);
   } catch (RemoteException e) {
        return TETHER_ERROR_SERVICE_UNAVAIL;
    }
  }
```

This method simply returns an mService object which is an IConnectivityMananger interface object. The tether() method is declared in this interface. However, the ConnectivityManager does not implement IConnectivityManager interface. So there has to be a class where this tether()method is implemented, but I am unable to find such a class. Any help in this regard is welcome

Answer (score 0):

`IConnectivityManager` is a remote interface. It is defined in `IConnectivityManager.aidl`. The `tether()` method is a part of the remote interface. When `mService.tether()` is called, this calls a remote method in the connectivity manager service (which is running in a remote process).